# Samba Configuration : Error

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

[image]
I'm new to Samba file sharing systems.I have attached simple diagram of my structure. I have an doubt with samba configuration file with folder and user permissions.

The end user will can login through with LDAP and access volumes and folder with permissions.

I think I need to wrote a big definition of samba configuration file.

Comment: You need to set up the linux system to use LDAP authentication (both PAM and NSS), then define shares for the appropriate groups, then define/allow users and groups to access. Probably better off asking on `unix.stackexchange.com` ... there is a browser based samba config tool - `swat` - but I'm not sure if it is still maintained, if it handles LDAP stuff or just basic config, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan Thank you. Quick search in google shows SWAT is available. i shall try the same.